# How to set envVars for multiproject?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have sbt multi projects and try to set the `envVars` in the `build.sbt` for subprojects as following:

```
envVars in Test := Map("KAFKA_SERVER" -> "localhost:9092")
```

the test abort with following message:

```
[info]   java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
[info]   at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:349)
[info]   at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:347)
[info]   at io.khinkali.auth.AppSpec.<init>(AppSpec.scala:23)
[info]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

In the test file, I tried to get the value as following:

```
sys.env.get("KAFKA_SERVER").get
```

Intellj provides the set the environment variable as following:

[image]

How to set an environment variable in `sbt` for `subprojects` also?
**Update**

The root `build.sbt` looks as following:

```
name := "bary"

scalacOptions += "-Ypartial-unification"
scalacOptions += "-feature"
addCompilerPlugin("org.scalamacros" % "paradise" % "2.1.0" cross CrossVersion.full)


val Cats = "1.0.0"
val Shiro = "1.4.0"
val Logback = "1.2.3"
val CatsEffect = "0.5"
val Kafka = "1.0.0"
val Bean = "1.9.3"
val Circe = "0.9.0-M3"
val Log4j = "1.7.25"
val ScalaCheck = "1.13.4"
val Scalactic = "3.0.4"
val Scalatest = "3.0.4"
val JavaJwt = "3.3.0"
val Simulacrum = "0.11.0"
val Http4s = "0.18.0-M7"


lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  organization := "io.khinkali",
  version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT",
  scalaVersion := "2.12.4",
  envVars in Test := Map("KAFKA_SERVER" -> "localhost:9092"),
  fork in Test := true,
  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-simple" % Log4j,
    "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-core" % Logback,
    "org.apache.shiro" % "shiro-all" % Shiro,
    "org.typelevel" %% "cats-core" % Cats,
    "org.typelevel" %% "cats-effect" % CatsEffect,
    "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka-streams" % Kafka,
    "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka-clients" % Kafka,
    "commons-beanutils" % "commons-beanutils" % Bean,
    "io.circe" %% "circe-core" % Circe,
    "io.circe" %% "circe-generic" % Circe,
    "io.circe" %% "circe-parser" % Circe,
    "io.circe" %% "circe-literal" % Circe,
    "com.github.mpilquist" %% "simulacrum" % Simulacrum,

    "org.scalactic" %% "scalactic" % Scalactic,
    "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % Scalatest % "test",
    "org.scalacheck" %% "scalacheck" % ScalaCheck % "test",
  ),
  resolvers ++= Seq(
    "Sonatype OSS Snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
  ),
  fork in run := true,
)

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(commonSettings)
  .settings(
    name := "bary",
    organization := "io.khinkali",
    moduleName := "bary"
  ).
  aggregate(
    kafka_api,
    auth_stream,
    rest)

lazy val kafka_api = (project in file("kafka-api")).
  settings(commonSettings).
  settings(
    name := "kafka-api",
    moduleName := "kafka-api"
  )

lazy val auth_stream = (project in file("auth-stream")).
  settings(commonSettings).
  settings(
    name := "auth-stream",
    moduleName := "auth-stream",
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "com.auth0" % "java-jwt" % JavaJwt,
    )
  ).dependsOn(kafka_api)

lazy val rest = (project in file("rest")).
  settings(commonSettings).
  settings(
    name := "rest",
    moduleName := "rest",
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "org.http4s" %% "http4s-dsl" % Http4s,
      "org.http4s" %% "http4s-blaze-server" % Http4s,
      "org.http4s" %% "http4s-blaze-client" % Http4s,
      "org.http4s" %% "http4s-circe" % Http4s,
    )
  ).dependsOn(kafka_api, auth_stream)
```

I still got the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Any setting you want to apply to a subproject can either be specified just for that subproject or in `commonSettings`, as shown in `build.sbt` below.

You did not show your multiproject definitions, so here is a short example. There are many ways of setting up these types of projects, and I am not going to elaborate on the possible ways; this is a complicated topic, and it has evolved a lot over the years, especially recently.

```
lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  envVars in Test := Map("KAFKA_SERVER" -> "localhost:9092"),
  fork in Test := true, // required for envVars task to work
  javacOptions ++= Seq(
    "-Xlint:deprecation",
    "-Xlint:unchecked",
    "-source", "1.8",
    "-target", "1.8",
    "-g:vars"
  ),
  licenses += ("Apache-2.0", url("https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html")),
  version := "0.5.0"
)

lazy val demo = project
  .settings(commonSettings:_*)
  .settings(
    name := "demo"
  ).dependsOn(root)

lazy val root = (project in file("root"))
  .settings(commonSettings:_*)
  .settings(
    name := "root"
  )
```

One more important fact: The environment setting for `test` will not be respected when run with the IntelliJ IDEA test runner. As a workaround, you can set environment variables in the `Run/Debug Configurations` -> `Environment variables` window. When you run `sbt test`, however, the environment variable specified in `build.sbt` will be set.

Normally, the only way to apply an environment variable to a process is to start the process with that environment variable. If you want SBT to run your program in an environment with a certain environment variable, it will need to be launched in a new environment. This is called [forking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(system_call)).

Comment: Looks like the runtime environment does not have a definition for `KAFKA_SERVER`. If you launch from IDEA you should read https://stackoverflow.com/a/38543637/553865

Comment: I know how to set it in IDEA but not in SBT. When I write test, it should take the environment variable from build.sbt where I set it.

Comment: Did you set `fork in Test := true`?

Comment: I added a new paragraph at the end of my answer. I think this solves the mystery.

Comment: What does `fork` mean?

Comment: Fork has many possible meanings, but in this context it is an operation whereby a process creates a copy of itself. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(system_call)

Comment: I mean, what does it mean in relation the code above. I did as you show me above, but I did not get the `environment` variable.

Comment: I appended an explanatory paragraph to my answer. HTH

Comment: Please look at the update section above. I still do not get the environment variable in test.

Comment: This is a link to an issue in sbt repository mentioning that forking is required for envVars to work: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/3914